# Why ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 project wont let me sign in with a register user using Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identity

I have scaffolded the Login View to create my own, but the thing is that whenever I tried to Login to the application an invalid login attempt error appears as if it is not finding the user. Cant seem to find a solution to this. Can someone help me please!!!

This is the code I'm using and it was autogenerated:

```
 var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);                
if (result.Succeeded)
{
   _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
   return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
{
   return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
}
if (result.IsLockedOut)
{
  _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
  return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
}
else
{
   ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
   return Page();
}
```

Comment: What's the error on the `result`? Does that user exist in the DB?

Comment: Did you confirm your Email?You mean that you use the scaffolded code and do not change anything?Could you share your Startup.cs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By using default scaffold Identity,I could reproduce your issue if you do not confirm your email.Here are two ways to resolve your issue.

1.You could click the following link to confirm the email like below:

[image]
2.Or you could set `RequireConfirmedAccount=false` like below:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(
             options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: thanks this was the issue, I did not pay any attention on the configuration

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail, It was hidden very well inside startup.cs

Comment: This implementation is a great time saver and thanks .NET team for doing that. But, authorization scaffolding is not implementing sending of mail and it's forcing the developer to click on that link just for account to be active, has cost me 1 hour of debugging and pulling my hair... @Rena, thanks for the help.